# How to print out all cells of a table row in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm just starting to learn how to use Beautiful Soup.

As an exercise, I picked [this page from ESPN](http://www.espn.com/espn/print?id=20443164).

There's a table in there with NBA players and their fantasy ranks.
I was able to print the whole row out and it shows everything I see in my browser.

However, when I go to print each cell by itself, it prints out "None" because for some reason, it can't parse a cell that contains an anchor

Here's my code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib2
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
   url = "http://www.espn.com/espn/print?id=20443164"
   resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.read())

   table = soup.find_all("table")
   mytable = table[2]
   rows = mytable.findChildren(['th','tr'])
   print rows
   for row in rows:
       cells = row.findChildren('td')
       for cell in cells:
#           print cell.string  # line in question
           print cell  # line in question
```

If I use

```
print cell
```

I get the following output:

```
<td>1. <a href="http://www.espn.com/nba/player/_/id/3032977/giannis-antetokounmpo">Giannis Antetokounmpo</a>, SF/PF</td>
<td>PHI</td>
<td>C24</td>
```

If I use

```
print cell.string
```

I get the following output:

```
None
MIL
SF1
```

So how can I make everything print out without the "td" tags but recognize everything in the first cell without printing "None"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) regarding [**`.string`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) (emphasis mine):

> **`.string`**
>
> > - If a tag has only one child, and that child is a `NavigableString`, the child is made available as `.string`
> > - If a tag’s only child is another tag, and that tag has a `.string`, then the parent tag is considered to have the same `.string` as its child
> > - **If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what `.string` should refer to, so `.string` is defined to be `None`**

What they mean by *If a tag contains more than one thing* is that if a tag contains another tag, `tag.string` evaluates to `None`. That's the reason you are getting `None` for first the `<td>` tag in your code (as it contains another tag, `<a>`).

So, to get the complete text of a tag, you can use [**`get_text()`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text). So, in your code, use `cell.get_text()`.

Or, for this case, you could also use `cell.text`. `.text` is the same as `get_text()`, which you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/getanewsletter/BeautifulSoup4/blob/master/bs4/element.py):

```
text = property(get_text)
```

Comment: how did you know about the .text method?  I didn't see it in the documentation

Comment: Yeah it is not mentioned in the documentation. I guess I saw it used in one of the SO Q&A when I was learning it. That's why I mentioned get_text first, as it is well documented.

Answer (score 2):

try this at your last loop. change `cell.string` to `cell.text`

```
for cell in cells:
    print cell.text
```

Comment: thanks for the tip.  how did you know about this method (the text method)?  I didn't see it in the documentation.  I could be illiterate but i didn't find the string ".text"

Comment: @Classified in Jupyter you can do `obj.` and then hit tab and it will show all the attributes of an object. You can also dir `dir(obj)`. I usually poke around in Jupyter to get familiar with a library.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this -

```
print (cell.text)
```

This will get you text inside the cell skipping all the tags init.

Comment: how did you know about the .text method?  I didn't see it in the documentation

Comment: @Classified actually i followed a youtube tutorial to learn bs. It was metioned there :)